# Spring Boot Rest Controller showing data on get request

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-restcontroller

So basically I have a Spring Rest Controller that returns an object.  I call the method from my JS file to retrieve data and it works great.  I know I can hide certain data and stuff but is there a way that I can hide the data showing in the browser.  What I mean by this is that when I call the method from my browser and not the js file it shows a blank html page with the JSON output of the object.  I would like to hide it from the browser view.

Comment: I suggest you read and understand when would you use spring's `@RestController` vs `@Controller` ( Or in general when would you send `html` from server to browser vs `json` to browser`). Then you could add a specific question if it is not clear

Answer (score -1):

Browser is actually the one who is sending the request for you. It adds request headers, compression etc on your behalf so their is no way you can hide your payload from browser. That's the way web work, if you want some essential details not to be read when response packets travel either encode-decode or encrypt-decrypt your response and use HTTPS.